# Meaning of if( item1 ? item2) : item3

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was looking through a java book and i remember reading something about using the ? operator for if statements an I cannot find the reading material anymore. I tried googling the topic but it yielded nothing. So how does the below piece of code

```
if( itemA ? itemB) : itemC
```

work

Comment: I think you mean either `if( itemA ? itemB : itemC)` or just `itemA ? itemB : itemC`. It's called a ternary/conditional operator/expression.

Comment: You're missing the right name when you search - 'ternary operator' or 'ternary conditional operator', e.g. https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: As shown it is just a syntax error that won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called ternary operator. Syntax will be like

```
(Condition) ? (Value to be assigned if the condition is true) : (Value to be assigned if the condition is false)
```

Look at the examples given below for understanding the usage

Eg.

```
public String getGender(String genderCode){

   return gender.equals("M")?"Male":"Female";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "?" ":" correspondans to the ternary operator

I.e : `a ? b : c` means "if a is true, return b, else return c"